# sshj or jsch, getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when deployed to Wildfly 10.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, jsch, wildfly-10, sshj

I have tried both these libraries and Wildfly is throwing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` on any class in use when my application is deployed.

Is there something in Wildfly that's blocking these libraries/or APIs that they use?

Comment: Are you including either library in your deployment?

Comment: Yes, it's there when I extracted the .ear file. My coworker just tried to deploy to Glassfish, same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In my `pom.xml` file of my EJB module, I added the following under `<configuration>` of `maven-ejb-plugin`:

```
<archive>
    <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
    </manifest>
</archive>
```